# Creating a Search bar c# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to create a search bar within my MVC application. I have the following model

```
    public class Project
{
    public int projectID { get; set; }
    public int customerID { get; set; }
    public int departmentID { get; set; }
    public string projectName { get; set; }
    public int employeeID { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a search bar within my index view allowing users to search the list of projects by entering either the projectID or the projectName. So far I have it searching on projectName but I am unsure how (or if it's possible) to search by ID or both at the same time. 
This is the search bar in my Index view :

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<p>
    Name  : @Html.TextBox("SearchName")<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</p>
}
```

This is my controller method

```
    public ActionResult Index(string searchName)
    {

        var projects = from pr in db.projects select pr;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchName))
        { 
            projects = projects.Where(c =>  c.projectName.Contains(searchName));
      }

        return View(projects);
      }
```

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: can you just use the same box and check both values in your query?.. `projects = projects.Where(c =>  c.projectName.Contains(searchName) || c.projectID == searchNameInt);`?  (create new int var and try cast searchname to int beforehand)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using OR Operators in Where Clauses**

You can take advantage of a simply OR `||` operator to test one or more properties within a single query within the [`Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) clause :

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchName)
{
      // Current projects
      var projects = db.Projects;
      // Filter down if necessary
      if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchName))
      {
          projects = projects.Where(p => p.projectName.Contains(searchName) || p.projectName.Contains(searchName));
      }
      // Pass your list out to your view
      return View(projects.ToList());
  }
```

**Handling Different Types**

Likewise, if you have multiple properties of different types, you could consider parsing your term if possible and using that :

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchName))
{
    // Normal search term
    var term = searchName;
    // Attempt to parse it as an integer
    var integerTerm = -1;
    Int32.TryParse(searchName, out integerTerm);
    // Now search for a contains with the term and an equals on the ID
    projects = projects.Where(p => p.projectName.Contains(term) || p.projectId == integerTerm);
}
```